# Tensorflow has no attribute 'svd'

Tags: tensorflow, svd

The documentation indicate that tensorflow has a svd operator.
However, I can't find it in my tensorflow with pip for python2.7 
I used these command on Mac:

```
 pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.8.0-py2-none-any.whl
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install tensorflow 0.8. The SVD was introduced in tensorflow 0.10. Try installing a more recent version. (Current version is 1.2).